# Counting Different Instance of Records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am required to count all the instances of quotes in the system based on the following criteria for table .

Table 1

```
Quote Number | Quote Version |
1            | A
1            | A
2            | B
2            | C
```

So you may see 2 quotes . Apparently I need to count 3 Not 2 , as I need to consider the different quote versions as an individual quotes.

So I was thinkin od adding a column say Quote Count and adding a 1 for every occurance of a quote , but sure how to structure it in sql ?

I need to add the number of quotes in this table at a later point in the process so thought i could just go to this column and do a count of the records in table with a Quote Count=1 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT [Quote Number], [Quote Version]
    FROM Table1
    ) s
```

No need to add a column, it is easily achieved with a query